# Grouping data by Each Monday not working as intended

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

**Objective:**

I'm trying to aggregate data by week where the start date is Monday and end date is Sunday.

**Intended Result:**

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
|   Date   |   Name    | WeekDate |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1/1/2018 | Monday    | 1/1/2018 |
| 1/2/2018 | Tuesday   | 1/1/2018 |
| 1/3/2018 | Wednesday | 1/1/2018 |
| 1/4/2018 | Thursday  | 1/1/2018 |
| 1/5/2018 | Friday    | 1/1/2018 |
| 1/6/2018 | Saturday  | 1/1/2018 |
| 1/7/2018 | Sunday    | 1/1/2018 |
| 1/8/2018 | Monday    | 1/8/2018 |
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

**What actually happens:**

```
+------------+------------+
|    date    |  WeekDate  |
+------------+------------+
| 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-01 |
| 2018-01-02 | 2018-01-01 |
| 2018-01-03 | 2018-01-01 |
| 2018-01-04 | 2018-01-01 |
| 2018-01-05 | 2018-01-01 |
| 2018-01-06 | 2018-01-01 |
| 2018-01-07 | 2018-01-08 |
| 2018-01-08 | 2018-01-08 |
+------------+------------+
```

**Code:**

```
    select 
         cast(dateadd(week,DATEDIFF(week,0, [date]),0) as date) AS Date
        ,count(user_id) AS count
    from ##data
```

**Why is January 7th put into 2018-01-08 group when it should be in 2018-01-01.**

Comment: Subtracting a day then adding back would have worked: `dateadd(day, 1, cast(dateadd(week,DATEDIFF(week,0, dateadd(day, -1,[date])),0) as date))`

Comment: The reason yours didn't work is that while it collapses  into weeks it still relies on the definition that a week is Sunday to Saturday. When you overlay any one of your desired week you'll see that it spans two different "datediff" weeks.

Comment: @shawnt00 thank you! but then I tried changing DATEFIRST to 1 but it didn't do anything...

Comment: Right. But of you check the documentation on `datediff` it says that `datefirst` doesn't change its behavior in order for it to remain a deterministic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the following date arithemtics:

```
set datefirst 1;
select 
     d.*,
     dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(weekday, [date]), [date]) AS first_day_of_week,                     from ##data d;
```

The first instruction defines Monday as the first day of the week. Then, `date_part()` gives you a number that represents the day of the week, that you can use to offset the date to the previous Monday.

Comment: perfect, but out of curiosity, do you have any explanation as to why my code didn't work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISO_WEEK for grouping data weekly as shown below.
You can check how ISO_WEEK interpreting your data [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=75d7968f5e8891b800f3fa3c4abcdbc4)

```
select *, datepart(ISO_WEEK,Date) WeekNumber
from your_table
```

For your exact required output, you can try this below logic-

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cb213df10ad84e1ba57f59964cde716d)

```
select *, 
DATEADD(
    DD,
    -
    CASE 
        WHEN datepart(weekday,date) = 1 THEN 7 
        ELSE datepart(weekday,date) - 1
    END + 1,
    DATE
)
from your_table
```